# "jump" to directory in ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to create an alias in ipython to "jump" to a directory. For example, I generally work in my home and scratch directories, and it would be awesome if I can easily switch between these directories. In bash, this is done by the line

```
alias sd='cd /scratch/users/"
```

How is this done in ipython? Specifically, I'm using ipython version 0.11.

I looked at `$alias`, but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Defining your own IPython magic functions is explained [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#defining-your-own-magics).

You'll want to use `chdir()` from the [os](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-parameter) module to change your working directory.

Comment: This seems to be for ipython version 1.0. I'm using version 0.11. I'll edit the question for clarity.

Comment: Ah! The IPython 0.11 magic documentation is [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.11/api/generated/IPython.core.magic.html). At the very least you can just `import os` and then `os.chdir('/this/dir')`.

Comment: The best I came up with is setting bookmarks in ipython by typing in the ipython command line %bookmark name dir and then I'm able to cd name to arrive at the bookmarked directory. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Did you see [this](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.11/api/generated/IPython.core.magic.html#IPython.core.magic.Magic.magic_cd)?